# jquery mouse selection not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a mouse selection using jQuery, this is what I am trying, it works but there is a bug: if I start the selection and move the mouse in circle, the selection breaks... How can I solve it?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7mo64ns/)

```
distanceStart = 0;
distanceEnd = 0;
mousedown = false;

$(window).on('mousedown',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mousedown = true;
    distanceXStart = e.clientX;
    distanceYStart = e.clientY;
    $div = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'class'
    }).appendTo('body');
});

$(window).on('mouseup',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mousedown = false;
    $div.remove();
});

$(window).on('mousemove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(mousedown){
        distanceXEnd = e.clientX;
        distanceYEnd = e.clientY;
        distanceX = (distanceXEnd - distanceXStart);
        distanceY = (distanceYEnd - distanceYStart);
        if(distanceX > 0 && distanceY > 0){
            $div.css({
                'left': (e.clientX - (distanceX/*/2*/)),
                'top': (e.clientY - (distanceY/*/2*/)),
                'width': distanceX,
                'height': distanceY
            });
        }else
        if(distanceX < 0 && distanceY < 0){
            $div.css({
                'left': e.clientX,
                'top': e.clientY,
                'width': (1-distanceX),
                'height': (1-distanceY)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A bit vague. Explain some more

Comment: What do you mean by selection breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, you just forgot the other two conditions to check on:  `distanceX < 0` OR `distanceY < 0`

**[Here's a demo using your original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7mo64ns/3/)**

And here's what I added just after that second `else if` ends:

```
// ... stuff
else if ( distanceX < 0 ) {
    $div.css({
        'left': e.clientX,
        'top': e.clientY - distanceY,
        'width': (1 - distanceX),
        'height': distanceY
    });
}
else if ( distanceY < 0 ) {
    $div.css({
        'left': e.clientX - distanceX,
        'top': e.clientY,
        'width': distanceX,
        'height': (1 - distanceY)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this type of interactivity with HTML5 `canvas`. https://jsfiddle.net/nbwLr27s/1/

Canvas is nice for this sort of thing since it gives you full control over the shapes you'd like to display and performs very well since there's no DOM manipulation involved.

With canvas `fillRect`, all you need is the start x, start y, width and height. I used the following code:

```
  var leftmost = Math.min(start_x, coords.x)
  var rightmost = Math.max(start_x, coords.x)
  var lowest = Math.min(start_y, coords.y)
  var highest = Math.max(start_y, coords.y)
  ctx.fillRect(leftmost, lowest, rightmost - leftmost, highest - lowest)
```